# Pycharm не запускает библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI, написано что нет связи с сервисом?

Tags: pycharm, telebot, python-3.8

Новичок в мире Питона..
Написала код для телеграмм бота. Запускаю в pycharm , написано что нет соединение с сервесом. На pycharm установлен pip, библиотека yTelegramBotAPI.
Не судите строго. Не пойму что не так . pip и  библиотека yTelegramBotAPI установлена новая версия проверил.
код: bot = telebot.TeleBot(')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
if message.text == "Привет":

```
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, сейчас я расскажу тебе гороскоп на сегодня.")

elif message.text == "/help":

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши Привет")

else:

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
```

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
Я так понял с кодом все ок.
Ошибка :

```
2020-08-09 13:07:59,135 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\\\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 285, in __retrieve_updates
updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 255, in get_updates
json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 206, in get_updates
return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 69, in _make_request
return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 88, in _check_result
raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']
"
2020-08-09 13:07:59,136 (__init__.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']"
2020-08-09 13:08:02,529 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\\\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 285, in __retrieve_updates
updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 255, in get_updates
json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 206, in get_updates
return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 69, in _make_request
return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
2020-08-09 13:08:02,530 (__init__.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']"
2020-08-09 13:08:03,140 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\\\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 285, in __retrieve_updates
updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 255, in get_updates
json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 206, in get_updates
return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 69, in _make_request
return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 88, in _check_result
raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']
2020-08-09 13:08:09,413 (__init__.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']"
2020-08-09 13:08:13,531 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\\\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 285, in __retrieve_updates
updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 255, in get_updates
json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 206, in get_updates
return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 69, in _make_request
return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
File "D:\Soft\python\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 88, in _check_result
raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']
"
2020-08-09 13:16:38,243 (__init__.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: can\'t use getUpdates method while webhook is active; use deleteWebhook to delete the webhook first"}']"
```

Comment: Данная ошибка говорит, что ваш Токен уже используется или вы его ввели не верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видите эту строчку - `ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful.`
Это значит что вам нужно проверить ваш Api Бота в Телеграме.
Для Этого зайдите в [Бот фазер](https://t.me/BotFather), напишите /mybots и выберете вашего бота, нажмите на кнопку "Api Token" И он вам выдаст токен бота, дальше нажмите "revoke current token" и возьмите новый токен, который будет в том же сообщении. И последнее - поменяйте токен в коде

> [Bot Father](https://t.me/BotFather)

Я могу ошибаться, но с такой-же ошибкой я справлялся так-же:)